# jQuery Address plugin, browser doesn't refresh as it should

Tags: ajax, jquery, deep-linking, jquery-address

I am using jQuery address plugin in the following way:
1. user visits main site (example.com)
2. user clicks in article title. Address plugin changes the address to (example.com/article-1) and Ajax loads the article into the page.
3. user "closes" this article. Address plugin changes the address to (example.com) and removes the article from the page.

If the user presses back/forward button the page will go back/forward this steps.

This is the workflow. However I noticed a problem when the user is in step 2 (article is loaded). (example.com/article-1) links to the real article page. So if in that step the user presses reload browser button goes to the article-unique-page. This is expected. But if he presses the back button, then the address changes to (example.com) (expected) but doesn't reload the page, it gets stuck in this article-unique-page when it should reload as it would normally without the plugin to (example.com).

```
$.address.state('example.com');

$.address.change(function(event) {

    if (event.value == 'example.com') {

        close_article();
        $.address.value('');

    } else {

        open_article();
        $.address.value(event.value);

    }

});
```

Comment: Is there any other relevant code you could post that might help to understand the problem? Have you found an answer or did you end up just moving on?

Comment: I ended up changing to History.js plugin